# MySQL WorkBench failed to connect to Mysql at XXX.XXX.XXX with user root [Host to Vmware]

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, vmware-player

I installed mysql 5.6.20 in vmware win XP, While trying to connect the database from the host [windows 7] using MYSql Workbench. In vmware NAT is enabled. also with DHCP

Failed to Connect to my sql at XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX with user root

Advance Thanks

Comment: Is "bind-address" set to the server-ip not localhost?

Comment: @jens yes, also the pwd is correct even I turned off firewall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the answer, Just adding a new user with all privileges in Mysql and the connection got established in Mysql workbench.

```
  mysql> CREATE USER 'randxy'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root_password';
  mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'randxy'@'localhost'
   ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
  mysql> CREATE USER 'randxy'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
  mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'randxy'@'%'
   ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```